# Writing to an open excel file

Tags: python, excel, windows, pywin32

I want to write to an open excel sheet.
I did this:

```
import win32com.client

app = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
```

but got errors:

```
AttributeError: module 'win32com.gen_py.00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9' 
  has no attribute 'CLSIDToClassMap'
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python-win32com excel com model started generating errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889704/python-win32com-excel-com-model-started-generating-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using pandas library for this:

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
                   index=['row 1', 'row 2'],
                   columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```