# Can't copy a cell information using Win32com library

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, pyautogui

So basically I'm creating a automation that copy a information from a cell and save it in to a var so i can paste in to a app like notepad or wathever

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pyautogui
import global_variables


def copiar():
    try:
        excel = win32.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
    except:
        print("Excel not found.")
        return

    # Obter o nome da planilha ativa
    workbook_name = excel.ActiveWorkbook.Name

    # Se a planilha ativa não for a desejada, você pode abrir a planilha usando o seu caminho
    if workbook_name != 'CONEMB_ZLE.xlsx':
        # Exibe uma mensagem de aviso
        print("Excel not found, open.")
        return

    # Tornar o Excel visível
    excel.Visible = True

    # Selecionar a planilha ativa
    sheet = excel.ActiveSheet

    # Obter o valor da célula selecionada
    global_variables.valor_global = sheet.Application.Selection.Text

    # Imprimir o valor
    #print(global_variables.valor_global)

copiar()
```

It was working until today, I don't know why its doesnt recognize my Excel archive anymore, it prints `excel not found` but the Excel is opened with the same archive

I use it this way because i don't want to have to put the archive location I'm 3 hours tryng to fix that and i use my Excel archives on my Onedrive.

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\bissojhe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\py32.py", line 36, in <module> copiar() File "C:\Users\bissojhe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\py32.py", line 8, in copiar excel = win32.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\bissojhe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client_init_.py", line 96, in GetActiveObject return __WrapDispatch(dispatch, Class, resultCLSID=resultCLSID, –
```

Comment: There are two places in code which can print "Excel not found". Which one prints your error?

Comment: To be clear, it's the `win32.GetActiveObject()` call failing? I'd suggest focusing the question on that call, not on the logic you _would_ invoke later if that call succeeded.

Comment: It would also do you a great deal of good to take out the `try`/`except` so the original exception actually gets printed and you can see the exact error instead of replacing it with your own less-useful one. At minimum, we want that original exception present in the question's text.

Comment: @MichaelButscher the first except

Comment: @CharlesDuffy now its trowing a error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bissojhe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\py32.py", line 36, in <module>
    copiar()
  File "C:\Users\bissojhe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\py32.py", line 8, in copiar
    excel = win32.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bissojhe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 96, in GetActiveObject
    return __WrapDispatch(dispatch, Class, resultCLSID=resultCLSID,

Comment: HEY GUYS I JUST FIXED!! just by deleting a folder called gen_py on the temp folder, i just cant believe it OMG

Comment: [Edit] that traceback (the whole thing, not a trimmed excerpt) _into the question_ rather than putting it in a comment -- we want the question to have enough details that someone else also having problems using Excel from Python can tell, using only the question's content, if their problem has the same cause as yours (and thus whether your question's solutions will be useful to them). And when answering your own question, do that by clicking the "add your answer" button, not editing the answer into the question.

Comment: (Also, make sure this isn't duplicative of [python win32com excel model started generating errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889704/python-win32com-excel-com-model-started-generating-errors), which is answered suggesting that same resolution).

Comment: You should answer your own question rather than adding the answer in the question