# SEARCH Outlook inbox using Python

Tags: python, email, search, outlook, mapi

I'm successfully connecting to and reading through my Outlook inbox using some code modified from: [Reading e-mails from Outlook with Python through MAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077625/reading-e-mails-from-outlook-with-python-through-mapi). What I'd like to do is search my inbox for certain email subjects. I can do this by just looping through all emails but wondering if there is a more elegant (perhaps using MAPI) way to *search* the inbox? I've looked through the [MailItem methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_methods.aspx) but can't seem to find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the AdvancedSearch method of the Application class which allows to search for items in multiple folders. The [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) and [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) methods of the Items class allow to search for items in the single folder only.

The key benefits of using the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the IsInstantSearchEnabled property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the Search class.

Read more about the `AdvancedSearch` method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article. Note, the Outlook object model is common for all programming languages, so it doesn't matter whether Python or C# is used.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted talks about using Outlook Object Model, not MAPI - Extended MAPI is a completely different API accessible from C++ or Delphi, but not from Python.

To search for an email, use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` (where Items collection comes from the `MAPIFolder.Items` property) - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268869.aspx for an example.