# pywin32 installation PermissionError:[Errno 13]

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook-2010

I'm trying to install `pywin32` using pip by following this [link](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32), but I get 
a:

> PermissionError:[Errno 13] Permission denied : ....\pythoncom.py

I'm using:

- Python 3.6.0
- pip 9.0.1
- Windows 10

I primarily want to install `pywin32` for accessing Outlook emails as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077625/reading-e-mails-from-outlook-with-python-through-mapi).

How can I solve this?

Comment: You don't have enough rights to do that, it seems. So, you have to get more rights from the admin.

Comment: @Geshode Does that mean I need the admin right to install it otherwise it wouldn't be installed in my PC? Is there any ways that we can installed it without Admin right?

Comment: @user2851376 yes you need to have admin rights to install, i changed my rights and i could install it succesfully.

Comment: @Tayyab I see...ok..thanks for the info! :)