# Extract emails from Outlook with Python

Tags: python, windows, email, outlook

I need to extract all emails in outlook mail and I tried this code and it works

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15904604/10718214

but my question is there any way to access an email without opening it on the device?

Comment: Please look into this. https://github.com/O365/python-o365

Comment: what do you mean by 'accessing an email without opening it' ? Can you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: I must open my email account on outlook app if I need to extract the emails, but can I do it without open it in the app?

Comment: thank you @NihalSangeeth

Comment: You mean Headless?